# What is the length of the longest decreasing sequence in integer matrix?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms

Given a finite $m \times n$ matrix $M$ with all distinct integers, we travel it following two simple rules:

- The travel can start from any cell, say, $M[i,j]$.
- At each cell $M[i,j]$, it computes the minimum $m$ of all its adjacent cells and itself, namely 
  $$m = \min(M[i,j], M[i-1,j], M[i+1, j], M[i, j-1], M[i, j+1]),$$
  and goes to the cell with the value $m$.
  Note that the travel is stuck if $m = M[i,j]$; it terminates in this case.

In this manner, each travel corresponds to a monotonically decreasing integer sequence. The question is:

> What is the length of the longest decreasing sequence(s)?
>   In other words, I am seeking for matrices that contain such sequences as long as possible.

---

*Note:* Since it can be easily modeled as a graph problem, I use the `graph-theory` tag.

Comment: Are you asking for the existence of matrix such that it is possible to construct the longest sequence with length of $O(nm)$? It is possible to construct such matrix. If the matrix is generated randomly, then with high probability, the length should be around $\log nm$ (or something like that).

Comment: @Irvan Yes, I am seeking for the matrix that makes such sequences as long as possible. Do you mean it is possible to construct an $m \times n$ matrix that contains a sequence (as defined in the problem) of length $O(mn)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will illustrate a $5x5$ matrix that gives such sequence of length $O(nm)$. The extension should be easy to see.

```
1  2  3  4  5
X  X  X  X  6
11 10 9  8  7
12 X  X  X  X
13 14 15 16 17
```

You should replace X with some large number (e.g., $nm+1$). If you start from the bottom right, the length of your sequence is at least $\frac{mn}{2}$.

Comment: I see. Thanks. What about the average case (the $\log (mn)$ in your comment)?

Comment: If the matrix is a permutation of $1, \cdots, nm$ picked uniformly at random, and if you select the starting position at random, then I think the expected length of the sequence is (probably) $\log nm$ (I'm not sure myself haha).